# Почему GWT CellTable не показывает все результаты?

Tags: java, gwt, ui, java-ee

Я получаю лист результатов, используя rpc call. Если отображать данные при помощи dialog box-а то все данные показаны полностью, но когда я загружаю их в cellTable видна только часть результатов.

```
public void onSuccess(List<List<String>> result) {   
    CellTable<List<String>> bugsTable = new 
    CellTable<List<String>>();
    // Create columns
    TextColumn<List<String>> idColumn = new TextColumn<List<String>>() {
            @Override
        public String getValue(List<String> recordSet) {
            return recordSet.get(0).toString();
        }
    };

    TextColumn<List<String>> idCommitColumn = new TextColumn<List<String>>() {
            @Override
        public String getValue(List<String> recordSet) {
                return recordSet.get(1).toString();
        }
    };

    TextColumn<List<String>> erMessageColumn = new TextColumn<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(List<String> recordSet) {
                    return recordSet.get(2).toString();
            }
    };

    // Add the columns.
    bugsTable.addColumn(idColumn, "ID");
    bugsTable.addColumn(idCommitColumn, "ID commit");
    bugsTable.addColumn(erMessageColumn, "Message");

    // Set the total row count. This isn't strictly necessary, but it affects
    // paging calculations, so its good habit to keep the row count up to date.
    bugsTable.setRowCount(result.size(), true);

    // Push the data into the widget.
    bugsTable.setRowData(0, result);
    tabP.add(bugsTable, "bugs");
    RootPanel.get("loadingbarImg").setVisible(false);
}
```

Приложение на java + gwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что помимо  `bugsTable.setRowCount(result.size(), true);` нужно еще установить количество записей на страницу `bugsTable.setPageSize(result.size());`. Неочевидно, по моему.